# VBScript file locked after executing

Tags: vbscript

My VBScript file is being locked after it has been executed. I am currently developing it and so am writing bits of script, then test running it. However after it finishes and I try to make more edits to the script, I can't because Windows has locked it. I need to use Process Explorer (sys internals app) to delete the handle to the file.

*EDIT: I am developing the script in my base machine and running the script within a VM (virtual machine). Process Explorer tells me the script is being locked by VMWare-vmx.exe which is the VM instance, but running PE and searching for the script file within the VM yields no results..*

I found a script to check what VBscripts are running, and it doesn't appear to still be running, just locked for some reason...

My script is connecting to ADODB objects which I'm closing the connections to at the end.

Here is my script, if it helps:

```
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim fso
Dim objShell

Dim IBM_Conn
Dim IBM_RS
Dim IBM_Field

Dim Loc_Conn

'create an instance of the ADO connection and recordset objects
Set IBM_Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set IBM_RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set Loc_Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'open the connection to the database
IBM_Conn.Open "DSN=IBMSeriesIData64"
Loc_Conn.Open "DSN=TanksDatabase64"

'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records 
IBM_RS.Open "SELECT STANK, SBREG, SBVIN, SBCAT, SBCLS, SBSPC, SBBCH, SBSTS, SLITRE, SFULL from BWSTK" ,IBM_Conn

'first of all determine whether there are any records 
If IBM_RS.EOF Then
    'Write to the log file
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
    Set objFile = fso.GetFile(strPath)
    strPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 
    strPath = strPath & "\ErrLog.txt"
    MsgBox strPath
    If Not fso.FileExists(strPath) Then
        fso.CreateTextFile(strPath)
    End If
    Set LogFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath, ForAppending)
    LogFile.WriteLine Now & " - Error updating IBM Series i tank data; No records found for query: 'SELECT STANK, SBREG, SBVIN, SBCAT, SBCLS, SBSPC, SBBCH, SBSTS, SLITRE, SFULL from BWSTK'"
    LogFile.Close
Else
    'Ensure all records are deleted from the staging data table
    Loc_Conn.Execute "DELETE FROM datIBM_Series_i_RawData_Staging"

    'Loop through each row in the recordset and insert it into the staging  table
    Do While NOT IBM_RS.EOF
        sTank = IBM_RS("STANK").Value
        sRegion = IBM_RS("SBREG").Value
        sVintage = IBM_RS("SBVIN").Value
        sCategory = IBM_RS("SBCAT").Value
        sClass = IBM_RS("SBCLS").Value
        sSpec = IBM_RS("SBSPC").Value
        sBatch = IBM_RS("SBBCH").Value
        sStatus = IBM_RS("SBSTS").Value
        fVolCurrent = IBM_RS("SLITRE").Value
        fVolCapacity = IBM_RS("SFULL").Value

        'Create the insert statement
        Loc_SQL = "INSERT INTO datIBM_Series_i_RawData_Staging (Tank, Region, Vintage, Category, Class, Spec, Batch, Status, VolCurrent, VolCapacity) VALUES ("
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + "'" + sTank + "'"
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + ",'" + sRegion + "'"
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + ",'" + sVintage + "'"
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + ",'" + sCategory + "'"
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + ",'" + sClass + "'"
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + ",'" + sSpec + "'"
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + ",'" + sBatch + "'"
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + ",'" + sStatus + "'"
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + "," + CStr(fVolCurrent)
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + "," + CStr(fVolCapacity)
        Loc_SQL = Loc_SQL + ")"

        Loc_Conn.Execute Loc_SQL

        IBM_RS.MoveNext   
    Loop

    'Move the staging data into the production table
    Loc_Conn.BeginTrans
    Loc_Conn.Execute "DELETE FROM datIBM_Series_i_RawData"
    Loc_Conn.Execute "INSERT INTO datIBM_Series_i_RawData SELECT * FROM datIBM_Series_i_RawData_Staging"
    Loc_Conn.Execute "DELETE FROM datIBM_Series_i_RawData_Staging"
    Loc_Conn.CommitTrans
End If

'close the connection and recordset objects to free up resources
IBM_RS.Close
Set IBM_RS = Nothing
IBM_Conn.Close
Loc_Conn.Close
Set IBM_Conn = Nothing
Set Loc_Conn = Nothing
MsgBox "End"
```

Comment: Nope, it's not locked by my editor. Actually, I am editing my script in my base machine and running my script within a VM. Within Process Explorer I see that the file is locked by VMWare-vmx.exe which is the VM instance. I ran Process Explorer within the VM but couldn't find any app that was locking the script...

Comment: Type `Openfiles /local on` Reboot, then `openfiles /query /v` to display the program. Or does it happen in notepad which doesn't lock files it is editing.

Comment: There is nothing else that would lock it.

Comment: FYI: I added more info to my comment above after you commented

Comment: Just remove the msgbox at the end.